# How to set form value to NULL

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to set the value of form to NULL. Doing the below will just store the first letter of null in the database, so private will become "N" in the db when the I submit the form using this approach below. I definitely need the value in the db to changed to NULL and not '' empty.

```
<input type="hidden" name="private" value=NULL>
```

The database insert does work fine. Here it is:

```
$priv = $_POST['private'];
$sql = "UPDATE wp_users SET privacy = :private WHERE ID = :ID";
$stmt3 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt3->bindParam(':ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt3->bindParam(':private', $priv, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt3->execute();
```

Comment: Put quotes around NULL, but then still it will get interpreted as a string

Comment: Can you post the PHP code from the database submission?

Comment: just did that for you

Comment: All input from form submits comes over as strings, except for arrays when you suffix `[]`. There's no choice but to use a string comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the value of the private field, then you need to update the field to be null.

For example:

```
if($_POST["private"] == "NULL"){
    query("UPDATE `table` SET `private`= NULL")
}
```

Don't forget the quotes in your input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="private" value="NULL">
```

Notice that the value null (in the query) is not a string.

Edit after question update with code:

You should make the $priv null.

```
$priv = $_POST["private"];
if($priv == "NULL"){
    $priv = null;
}
```

One liner:

```
$priv = ($_POST["private"] == "NULL") ? null : $_POST["private"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't enough to make the value empty? `value=""`

```
<input type="hidden" name="private" value="">
```

Then

`$priv = $_POST["private"]; 
// $priv = NULL`

Comment: No, because this will return empty string ""